# Count rows from a related table

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query to gather data for a report:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as inspected, 
count(*) filter(where status='fail') as failed, 
count(*) filter(where status='deficient') as impaired, 
count(*) filter(where status='pass') as passed, 
device_types.name
FROM inspection_data 
INNER JOIN devices ON devices.id=inspection_data.device_id 
INNER JOIN device_types ON devices.device_type_id=device_types.id 
WHERE inspection_id = 3
GROUP BY device_types.id 
ORDER BY device_types.name
```

This query is working as intended (Though I'm sure could be optimized somewhat. SQL isn't my strong suit). The problem is that I now want to gather one more summary datum. I want to count the number of each device_type_id in the devices table for this location_id.

I'll try to map out the database tables:

```
|     devices    | device_types | inspection_data |
|:--------------:|:------------:|:---------------:|
| id             | id           | id              |
| device_type_id | name         | inspection_id   |
| location_id    |              | device_id       |
|                |              | status          |
```

So when I run the query, I'm receiving results similar to this:

```
| inspected | failed | impaired | passed | name                       |
|:---------:|:------:|:--------:|--------|----------------------------|
| 6         | 0      | 2        | 4      | Air Sampling Type Detector |
| 9         | 1      | 1        | 7      | Alarm Bell                 |
```

And this is great. My hangup is that not all devices for a location have to be inspected during an inspection. So for example, let's say there are actually 15 "Alarm Bell" devices for this location, but only 9 were inspected as part of this inspection, as per the table above. How do I go about including another column in this output, named "total" with a value of 15 for the Alarm Bell device type, and so on for each of the device types in the report?

I hope I've adequately described what I'm trying to do. I am utterly stumped on how to go about this without running a second query, and I really don't want to do that unless absolutely necessary because it just clutters the code up even more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `left join`.  However, I'm not sure what table goes first.  My best guess is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total,
       COUNT(id.device_id) as inspected, 
       COUNT(id.device_id) filter (where status='fail') as failed, 
       COUNT(id.device_id) filter (where status='deficient') as impaired, 
       COUNT(id.device_id) filter (where status='pass') as passed,
       dt.name
FROM devices d INNER JOIN
     device_types dt
     ON d.device_type_id = dt.id LEFT JOIN
     inspection_data id
     ON d.id = id.device_id AND
        id.inspection_id = 3
GROUP BY dt.id 
ORDER BY dt.name
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now I just need to go over it tomorrow with a fresh mind to see what you did and why it works. Thanks for your help!